# using json data from localhost in js file using ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, localhost, rickshaw

I'm creating a web app that uses `MONGOHQ` to store data, and that uses Sinatra to run the app. If I go to: `localhost:4578/names.json`, I get the names of all the names that I use for my data. However, I'm having trouble accessing this data using the `getJSON` method of `jquery`.

The file `/names.json` looks like this:

```
["Yasiel Puig","Nick Franklin","Mike Zunino","Jurickson Profar","Manny Machado"]
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
var series = []
$.get('names.json', function(n) {
n.forEach(function(s) {
  series.push({
    name: s
  })
})
}, 'json')
```

But this does not really work. Do you have any other ideas for how I should access the json data? Could I save it to a var? I'm pretty sure the `json` data is not `JSONP` format, so maybe I should treat it as `AJAX`?

Comment: How do you know it "*does not really work?*" Have any errors occurred? Is the issue that `series` seems to remain empty?

Comment: A common beginner-writes-web-service issue is that you could be loading the html/javascript form the file system, and the browser will then block access to the web service. Have you arranged that the web service is also serving your html and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work, I tried it in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CTyP2/1/) Fiddle. Therefore the problem is probably on server side.

```
var data = ["Yasiel Puig", "Nick Franklin", "Mike Zunino", 
"Jurickson Profar", "Manny Machado"];

var series = [];
data.forEach( function( e ) {
        series.push( {
            name: e
        });
    }
);

series.forEach( function( e ) {
     console.log( e.name );   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could I save it to a var?

Possibly. Though, it depends on which variable and where/when you need it.

`$.get()` is asynchronous. It only starts the request, sets the callback as a listener, and then exits.

```
var series = [];

$.get('names.json', function (n) {
  n.forEach(function(s) {
    series.push({
      name: s
    });
  });

  // inside the callback...
  console.log(series); // filled: [ { name: "Yasiel Puig" }, ... ]
});

// after the request...
console.log(series);   // still empty: []
```

So, you can use `series`, or more importantly `n`, within the callback. Outside, it won't be available yet.

Comment: thanks jonathan. If I were to save it as a var, how would I do so?

Comment: @TimKaye You already are -- `series`. But, *where* and *when* you use that variable are the important parts. For a thorough explanation, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/.

Answer (score 0):

there is a difference between  calling `$.get('names.json')` and `$.get('/names.json')` I think you are not adding the starting `slash(/)` to the  url

when you call `$.get('names.json')` it calls `complete_current_url + '/names.json'`

eg. if you are on `/home` page then the url that would be called is `/home/names.json`

and `$.get('/names.json')`  will call `current_domain +  '/names.json'`

from any page it will always call `'/names.json'`